# Hibernate 3 cascade all not deleting existing record

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-onetomany

I have 3 classes A, B and C. And there relationships are:

1. One to many bi-directional from A to B.
2. C extends B.

I am able to add new records and edit existing records of address collection, but i am not able to remove any existing record.

Code to update Object

```
currentObj = getSession().merge(currentObj);
```

Mappings:

1. Address.hbm.xml

   ```
   <joined-subclass name="test.domain.ParticipantAddress"
           table="PARTICIPANT_ADDRESS"
           dynamic-update="false"
           dynamic-insert="false"
           lazy="true"
       >
       <key
           column="IDENTIFIER"
       />
       <many-to-one name="participant" class="test.domain.Participant"
           column="PARTICIPANT_ID" not-null="false" cascade="none" unique="true"/>

        <property
           name="sortOrder"
           type="long"
           update="true"
           insert="true"
           column="sortOrder"
           length="255"
       />
       </joined-subclass>
   ```
2. Participant.hbm.xml

   ```
       <list name="addressCollection" table="PARTICIPANT_ADDRESS"
       lazy="false"
       inverse="true"
       cascade="all">
           <cache usage="read-write"/>
           <key column="PARTICIPANT_ID"/>
           <list-index column="sortOrder"/>
           <one-to-many class="test.domain.ParticipantAddress"/>
   </list>
   ```

I also tried using cascade="all,delete-orphan" but it's also throwing error "A collection 
with cascade=”all-delete-orphan” was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance"

Answer (score 0):

Check what foreign key constraint you have in table B, if it doesn't allow deletion of A prior to B then you'll see this behavior. Remember that whatever you do on hibernate will be translated into SQL DML/DDL